# I would like to count instances of duplicate values across columns in my python data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to count instances of duplicate values across columns in my dataframe.

[image]

Comment: Something like this: `df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts(), axis=1).fillna(0).astype(int)`?

Answer (score 0):

Data:

```
np.random.seed(4)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(3,10, 40).reshape(5,8))
df.columns = ["Col_" + i for i in list('abcdefgh')]
```

df:

```
   Col_a  Col_b  Col_c  Col_d  Col_e  Col_f  Col_g  Col_h
0      5      9      8      4      3      3      5      4
1      5      7      8      9      4      3      7      5
2      7      9      9      5      7      6      3      8
3      8      4      9      8      9      3      5      9
4      8      9      3      4      5      5      3      3
```

```
f = df.apply(lambda x:x.value_counts(), axis=1)
df[f.columns] = f
df = df.dropna(how='all', axis=1)
```

df:

```
   Col_a  Col_b  Col_c  Col_d  Col_e  Col_f  Col_g  Col_h    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
0      5      9      8      4      3      3      5      4  2.0  2.0  2.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0
1      5      7      8      9      4      3      7      5  1.0  1.0  2.0  NaN  2.0  1.0  1.0
2      7      9      9      5      7      6      3      8  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  2.0  1.0  2.0
3      8      4      9      8      9      3      5      9  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  2.0  3.0
4      8      9      3      4      5      5      3      3  3.0  1.0  2.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0
```